# Enable SPFx extension on a document based on specific content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Can we enable SPFx extension on a document created based on a specific content type.

I want to enable (make visible) ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar based on the document of certain content type selected which will enable me to perform certain actions for specific documents.

Comment: You will need to add more description here. It first glance question does not seem to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported currently.

The List View commandset extension currently supports `RegistrationType="List"` and `RegistrationId="100"` which is the list template ID.

References - [Command Set Extension: Ability to set RegistrationType="ContentType" and RegistrationId="0x01"](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/871)

UserVoice Link - [Support RegistrationType "ContentType" in Command Set Extensions](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/33706687-support-registrationtype-contenttype-in-command)

However, you can show/hide your commandset based on content type value:

In the `onListViewUpdated` method, you can get the current items content type value and then show/hide your extension somewhat as:

```
public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
  const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
   if (compareOneCommand) {
    // ensure that atleast one item is selected
    if (event.selectedRows.length == 1) {

     // by default hide, the extension        

    compareOneCommand.visible = false;
    if(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName("ContentType") == "<your-content-type-name>"){

     // show the extension if it matches your content-type
     compareOneCommand.visible = true;
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - workaround to check ContentType manually and toggle visibility worked as expected for now.
one slight update I have to manually set visibility to false if condition not met. Visibility is bit temperamental in modern ui:
compareOneCommand.visible = false;

Comment: cheers, happy to help :)  You can accept it as answer by ticking the checkmark besides the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). By doing so, it will be removed from the unanswered section !